# Timeout error with PyVISA -- communicating with Agilent 34970A throug RS232 (USB)

Tags: python, serial-port, timeout

This is my first time i try to use `Pyvisa`, in order to communicate with an **`Agilent 34970A`**, using a `RS232` connection(using an USB port).

This is what's happening to me, inserting the basic first lines:

```
IN: import visa

IN: rm=visa.ResourceManager()

IN: print rm.list_resources()

(u'ASRL4::INSTR',)

IN: inst=rm.open_resource("ASRL4::INSTR")

IN: print inst.query("*IDN?")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 407, in query
    return self.read()

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 332, in read
    message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 306, in read_raw
    chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1582, in read
    ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler

    raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
```

> `pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.`

This timeout error happens everytime i try to read a value. I imposed also a larger timeout but nothing, i waited some minutes in vain. Any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match up your baud rate. Either on your 34970A or in the attributes of pyVisa.

The default that comes with visa is 9600.

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyvisa/master/pyvisa.pdf

here's an example if you wanted to change it to 115200, the highest baud on the 34970A.

```
inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL4::INSTR')
inst.baud_rate = 115200
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the RS232 setting protocol to be XON/XOFF.